# Entity Framework: custom include processing

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to add custom code (hook) to context in order to process queries like this:

```
var author = context.Authors.Include(e=>e.NotMappedClassField).Where...
```

Where NotMappedClassField is what it sounds: the class field with attribute [NotMapped]

In other words constract custom fields on the fly by an event.

Comment: If you want the navigation property, why put `[NotMapped]` on it?

Comment: I want propoerty but not mapped to the table. I would like to cinstruct it by myself. E.g. from allready mapped properties or just quering current context. Of course I could do it after linq query but I searh the possibility to integrate the linq query and  the method to construct NotMappedClassField to the "automagic".

Answer (score 1):

`.Include` does not do this. This call operates on *related entity types*. Using this eagerly loads associated entity types e.g. a one-to-many mapped table. For more examples, read [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) on MSDN.

If you are interested in learning how to modify query behavior, you will need to understand how EF6 and EF7 compile and execute queries. There is not simple hook for tying in custom query behaviors that are this different from default behavior. The source code is open-sourced at the links below:

EF6: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/

EF7: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework

Comment: It is clear that Include does not do this. It configure expression interpetation. And I search the way to inject my code to the expression interpetation.

Comment: Updated response above